# How to create a input button similar look & feel to a div so it can handle code-behind OnClick event

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pfq609xr/1/

Html:

```
<div class="btnAll btnExec">Execute SQL Job</div>
```

How can I achieve the same look & feel with a `button` instead of a `div`.

I am looking to execute code-behind code with the ASP.net onClick event which the standard DIV or ASP:Panel doesn't have.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what's wrong with changing `div` to `button`?

Comment: Simply change the `div` to `button`. Won't affect anything as the button is styled with the `css`.

Comment: @jaunt Just tried changing the `<div>` to `<button>` in OP's fiddle and I looked fine to me...

Comment: @vignesh Nothing changes. The calendar icon is there with the `button` tag too.

Comment: Thanks but I would need to be able to handle server side code with click event and button isn't a asp.net control

Comment: @SiKni8 `<asp:Button class="btnAll btnExec" Text="Execute SQL Job" runat="server" />` won't work ? I'm not familiar with asp.net but, doesn't that code work?

Comment: You might want to tag with ASP.net if you're looking specifically for a click event versus CSS styling.

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada You are absolutely right. I had a brain freeze! Thanks. The styling doesn't work correctly. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your `div` tag to `button` tag like this:

```
<button class="btnAll btnExec">Execute SQL Job</button>
```

Here's a fiddle with the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/pfq609xr/3/

---

In order to handle **click event**, you can either:

1. wrap "Execute SQL Job in an anchor tag with unique id like this:

`<button class="btnAll btnExec"><a id="checkBtn">Execute SQL Job</a></button>`

2. Wrap your button in a div like this:

`<div id="checkBtn"><button class="btnAll btnExec">Execute SQL Job</button></div>`

Now you can simple link the click event to `#checkBtn`.

---

For **ASP.NET**, you can use **OnServerClick** like this:

```
<button type="button" OnServerClick="btn_click" class="btnAll btnExec">Execute SQL Job</button>
```

Now simply link the click event to `btn_click`.

Comment: Thanks but I would need to be able to handle server side code with click event and button isn't a asp.net control

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just change div to a button ?

One problem is standard outline doesn't look beautiful with this button.